# Define a big array of integers in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to define an array of N = 1000000000 integers on the heap. My code is the following:

```
#define N 1000000000
int A[N];
```

But I am getting the following error when I try to compile my code:

[image]

This works for smaller numbers so why isn't it working now?

EDIT: After suggestions, I have defined A like this:

```
int *A = malloc(4000000000ULL);
```

I am now getting the error: Initializer element is not constant. It should also be noted that this is a global array.

Comment: Calculate the amount of memory that would be required for that number of integers.

Comment: Does that mean that my system ran out of RAM to allocate?

Comment: Assuming each `sizeof(int) == 4` you're asking for 4000000000B = 3.73GiB.  While you may have so much memory, you should allocate it with `int *A = malloc(1000000000 * sizeof(int));`.

Comment: That is on the stack

Comment: You can't initialize a file-scope variable with a run-time call to `malloc` like that - you'll need to declare it as `int *A;`, and then in `main` (or some other function), write `A = malloc( 4000000000ULL );`.  Note that this request may fail - you may not have a chunk of free memory that large.  Always check the result after calling `malloc`.

Comment: @JohnBode Is A still a global array if I define it like that? Because although I am not getting the error now and the code compiles, it is crashing after a while. The malloc is successful.

Comment: @Peter - Since you declared it ouside of any function, the variable `A` is global, yes.

Comment: @JohnBode Your previous comment solved my problem. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Do the malloc inside `main`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an `int` is 32 bits, you're trying to allocate 4GB of space.  And you're *not* allocating it on the heap.  You need to call `malloc` to do that.  If this variable is declared in a function, this space it getting allocated on the stack.  That's way too big.

Answer (score 0):

Your declared array is allocated on the stack, rather than the heap. Memory is allocated on the heap by calling [`malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html).

This leads to the error you're seeing here because the stack has a maximum size that isn't just bounded by the amount of RAM available. Per the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx), each thread has a max stack size, and this is configurable (or can be [set for a PE by the linker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35yc2tc3.aspx)).

In practice, it would be unusual to declare an array like this on the stack.

Comment: Caveat: I don't know anything whatsoever about developing on Windows.

Comment: It's on the stack only if the array is declared inside a function. It looks like OP declared it outside, having static storage duration.

Comment: @vsoftco true. In practice, I think the error message the poster is seeing has to do with going outside of the addressable space, rather than where the array lives.